# How do I send images along with other data using xmlhttprequest?

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I've been on this practically all day but I cannot figure out how xmlhttprequests work.

I can send strings and stuff one way, and I can send image files another way, but I cannot figure out how to send both of them at once.

I tried sending the image's dataUrl as a string, but it has multiple "+" in it which breaks it. This is how I learned to send an image (from a canvas) in a way that works, but I don't know how to modify it to take more information:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "uploadimg.php", false);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/upload");
xhr.send(canvas.toDataUrl());
```

And php:

```
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"])){

    $received = $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];
    $imageData = substr($received, strpos($received, ",")+1);
    $unencodedData = base64_decode($imageData);

    $fp = fopen("images/" . date("Y-m-d-G-i-s") . ".png", "wb");
    fwrite( $fp, $unencodedData);
    fclose( $fp );
}
```

Additionally, I would not know how to go about sending multiple files if I for some reason wanted to in the future.

I can't find good info about how xmlhttprequests really work, so for a large part I don't know what I'm doing besides copy pasting code. What would be a better way to do this, or how should I change it?

Comment: http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest.html https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @SLaks These don't do much for me because the whole http request is all ????? to me. I understand the javascript, and I mostly understand the PHP, but I have no idea how the computer actually sends and understands the data that is being transmitted.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a JSON string. For example:

```
xhr.send({
  image1: canvas1.toDataUrl(),
  image2: canvas2.toDataUrl(),
  image3: canvas3.toDataUrl(),
  some_string: 'some string here',
  number: 5,
  created_on: new Date()
});
```

Also the content type of the request needs to be `application/json`